# How to sort events descending using fullcalendar jquery pulgin

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have an array like `ARRAY_DATA`. Based on start time i want to sort events descending.

I tried out some of the things.but it won't works

Below is the code

```
ARRAY_DATA.sort(
   function(a,b) {
       return (a.start > b.start) ? 1 : ((b.start > a.start) ? -1 : 0);
   } 
);
```